# connecting a remote server database from a database funcion in postgresql9.1

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

Friends
i just want to know is it possible to connect another server database which is in same lan network from a store function of another database in postgresql 9.1

example
server a have a database function which will connect server b database table for querying data.

if some one have some code sample or idea please share that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long research i am able to do that
if any one require that please consider this and it will work fine.
my environment is ubuntu 12.04 64bit and postgres 9.1

first 
run

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

then 
in postgres prompt

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

now run the query like
SELECT *
FROM

```
 postgres=# dblink('host=123.456.78.9 port=5432 dbname=my_db user=sn password=adm123',
        'SELECT col1,col2 
         FROM schema.tbl_table')
         AS t (col1 numeric,col2 varchar);
```

just make sure that in the sharing server pg_hba.conf file there is an entry of 1st server.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to query a server from another server, if so, look at `dblink`function:

[dblink documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-function.html)